# Como acessar a variável $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Gostaria de saber como posso acessar o conteúdo da variável `scope` no AngularJS?

Teoricamente fiz tudo "correto", ou seja, declarando a variável no *controller* e atribuindo valores na mesma:

```js
var app = angular.module('vagalume', []);
app.controller('BandsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.teste = 'VALOR DE TESTE';
  this.lista = [
    {
      nome: 'U2',
      estilo: 'Rock'
    },
    {
      nome: 'Guns And Roses',
      estilo: 'Rock'
    },
    {
      nome: 'Scorpions',
      estilo: 'Rock'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="vagalume">
  <div class="artistas" ng-controller="BandsController as bandas">
    {{'TESTE:' + bandas.teste}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="banda in bandas.lista">{{banda.nome}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

O teste nunca retorna nada...

Link com o código: http://jsfiddle.net/v0pLv0ny/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ou muda `$scope.teste` para `this.teste` no js, que vai funcionar.

Ou no html muda `{{'TESTE:' + bandas.teste}}` para `{{'TESTE:' + teste}}`

Comment: Valeu cara era isso mesmo ! vlw

Answer (score 5):

Quando você acessa vincula a propriedade com a variável

`$scope.teste`

você não consegue acessar a mesma com o Alias do controller `{{bandas.teste}}`

você pode acessar ela da seguinte forma `{{teste}}`.

para acessar as propriedades criadas no Alias do controller, você tem que criar ela no controlador da seguinte forma.

`this.teste = valor` (This = Controller)

`app.controller('BandsController', function ($scope) { this == controller }`

Comment: Valeu pela descricao na diferença entre o this e o $scope !

Comment: +1 por descrever a razão correta. =)

Answer (score 2):

A referência para o escopo precisava ser corrigida. O exemplo abaixo mostra o seu conteúdo funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module('vagalume', []);
 app.controller('BandsController', function ($scope) {  
  $scope.teste = 'VALOR DE TESTE';
  $scope.lista = [
   {
    nome: 'U2',
    estilo: 'Rock'
   },
   {
    nome: 'Guns And Roses',
    estilo: 'Rock'
   },
   {
    nome: 'Scorpions',
    estilo: 'Rock'
   }
  ];
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="vagalume">
 <div class="artistas" ng-controller="BandsController as bandas">
  {{'TESTE:' + teste}}
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="banda in lista">{{banda.nome}}</li>
  </ul>  
 </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Valeu cara era isso mesmo ! vlw

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos sempre um prazer ajudar!